# Can I do string formatting in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

I am creating code like this:

```
var ds = "ds=" + encodeURIComponent($('#DataSource').val());
var ex = "ex=" + encodeURIComponent($('#EID').val());
var to = "to=" + encodeURIComponent($('#TID').val());
var st = "st=" + encodeURIComponent($('#SID').val());
window.location.href = '/person?' + ds + "&" + ex + "&" + to + "&" + st;
```

Is there some way in Javascript that I could use formatting to make the code look a bit cleaner? Also do I need to encode each element or can I just encode the variable abc?

Comment: Built-in.. NO.

But you can find an implementation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/4673436#4673436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot you can do, really.  You could alias the `encodeURIComponent` method and use an array with `join()` if you're looking for something *a little* neater:

```
var e = encodeURIComponent, 
    arr = [
        "ds=" + e($('#DataSource').val()),
        "ex=" + e($('#EID').val()),
        "to=" + e($('#TID').val()),
        "st=" + e($('#SID').val())
    ];

window.location.href = '/person?' + arr.join("&");
```

Comment: I like the idea of arr.join but do I need to do the encode on each element or could I just do it on the elements after they are joined up?

Comment: @SamanthaJ you need to encode each element other wise `&` is encoded.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I tried your suggestion and it works great. Thank you also to everyone else. I learned a lot from this post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<form>` and put your input tags in them and you can call `$('formContainer').serialize();`

Its better to use name-value pairs(query strings), while sending data to URI. provide names as id to all of the input tags that you wish to capture. You will get something like:

/person/DataSource=ds&EID=ex&TID=to&SID=st

-HTH

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write:

```
window.location.href = encodeURIComponent('/person?' + 
    $('#DataSource').val() + "&" 
    + $('#EID').val() + "&" + $('#TID').val() + "&"
    + $('#SID').val());
```

Comment: this will encode the `/`, `&` and `?` as well..

Comment: I was meaning some string format function that I see in other languages.

Comment: Oops, that's right Gaby. Sorry Samantha, don't use this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`sprintf()`](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)

Also this can help: [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "/person?ds=%x&ex=%x&to=%x&st=%x";

var tokens = [
  $("#DataSource").val(),
  $("#EID").val(),
  $("#TID").val(),
  $("#SID").val()
];

tokens.forEach(function (token) {
  str = str.replace("%x", encodeURIComponent(token));
});

location.href = str;
```

This will absolutely fall over if you have `%x` in your token string.

If you want a more generic solution try [`underscore.string`](http://epeli.github.com/underscore.string/)